# Laravel 5.1 Send mail error

Tags: php, email, laravel

I am working in Laravel 5.1 and trying to send email.
My Code

```
Mail::send('emails.contact-us', $data, function ($message) use ($data1) {
     $message->from($data1['email'], 'Laravel');
     $message->to('mohammed.yasir@alphaapp.com');
 });
```

and my config in .env is

```
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
 MAIL_PORT=465
 MAIL_USERNAME=email
 MAIL_PASSWORD=****
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

but when sending email its showing error

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 ih4sm8950014pbc.28 - gsmtp
"

where is my code is wrong any help?

Comment: Message is self explanatory, it says "Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"

Comment: But how i able to send email and overcome this problem?

Comment: provide correct credentials of your gmail in the .env file

Comment: I've just tried a fresh install of 5.1 with the exact settings above and it works fine. Your credentials are perhaps incorrect. Other option is in earlier versions of 5.0.x `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` wasn't a default .env replacement. Depending on your version of Laravel, it might not be being replaced. Have a look at `config/mail.php` to ensure that the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` env var is being used. The line should look like `'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),`

Answer (score 0):

Try activating less secure apps in your gmail acount https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Follow this file......

Change `"Username" => env('your-gmail-account@gmail.com')` to `"Username" => 'your-gmail-account@gmail.com';`

Same as Password...

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill",
    |            "ses", "sparkpost", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => ['address' => 'only5test@gmail.com', 'name' => 'shashikant parmar111'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    **'username' => 'Your-gmail-account@gmail.com',**

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    **'password' => '********',**

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => FALSE,

];
```